# How do I know from my VSIX that a build will be followed by a Debug session?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, vsix

I'd like my VSIX does something different in my `BuildEvents.OnBuildDone` handler, if the build has been triggered because the user wants to start a Debug session.

I've tried...

```
private void m_BuildEvents_OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope scope, vsBuildAction action) {
   if (m_DTE.Mode == vsIDEMode.vsIDEModeDebug) {
      //...
   }
}
```

...but unfortunately at that point `m_DTE.Mode` is not yet equal to `vsIDEMode.vsIDEModeDebug`.

I could start a one or two seconds timer and then check if `(m_DTE.Mode == vsIDEMode.vsIDEModeDebug)` but this is not a clean and reliable solution.

Can I know from querying the VSIX API somehow, either in `BuildEvents.OnBuildBegin` or `BuildEvents.OnBuildDone` handler, that a successful build will be followed by a Debug session?

Comment: You could determine that the debugger changes mode using IVsDebugger.AdviseDebuggerEvents that will be followed by a call to your implementation of IVsDebuggerEvents.OnModeChange() (with DBGMODE_Run) but this will happen *after* the build is done, so it's just a bit cleaner than a wait...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can monitor **Debug.Start** command invocation with **EnvDTE.CommandEvents**. See the following sample C# extension for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/):

```
public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    public void SetSite(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        events = DTE.Events;
        commandEvents = events.get_CommandEvents(null, 0);
        buildEvents = events.BuildEvents;
        commands = DTE.Commands as EnvDTE80.Commands2;

        commandEvents.BeforeExecute += OnBeforeExecute;
        commandEvents.AfterExecute += OnAfterExecute;

        buildEvents.OnBuildDone += OnBuildDone;
        buildEvents.OnBuildBegin += OnBuildBegin;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        commandEvents.BeforeExecute -= OnBeforeExecute;
        commandEvents.AfterExecute -= OnAfterExecute;

        buildEvents.OnBuildDone -= OnBuildDone;
        buildEvents.OnBuildBegin -= OnBuildBegin;
    }

    private void OnBeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        string name = GetCommandName(Guid, ID);
        if (name == "Debug.Start")
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OnBeforeExecute Debug.Start");
        }
    }

    private void OnAfterExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut)
    {
        string name = GetCommandName(Guid, ID);
        if (name == "Debug.Start")
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OnAfterExecute Debug.Start " + System.DateTime.Now.Second + "." + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        }
    }

    private void OnBuildDone(EnvDTE.vsBuildScope scope, EnvDTE.vsBuildAction action)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OnBuildDone " + System.DateTime.Now.Second + "." + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    }

    private void OnBuildBegin(EnvDTE.vsBuildScope scope, EnvDTE.vsBuildAction action)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OnBuildBegin " + System.DateTime.Now.Second + "." + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    }

    // throw()
    private string GetCommandName(string Guid, int ID)
    {
        if (Guid == null)
            return "null";

        string result = "";
        if (commands != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return commands.Item(Guid, ID).Name;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private EnvDTE.Events events;
    private EnvDTE.CommandEvents commandEvents;
    private EnvDTE.BuildEvents buildEvents;
    private EnvDTE80.Commands2 commands;
}
```

On my machine the sequence of events is following:

1. OnBeforeExecute `Debug.Start`
2. OnBuildBegin
3. OnAfterExecute `Debug.Start`
4. OnBuildDone

So, if you see this sequence, it will be followed by a Debug session.

---

To complete the Serge answer. Actually I observe this order:

1. OnBeforeExecute `Debug.Start`
2. OnAfterExecute `Debug.Start`
3. OnBuildBegin
4. OnBuildDone

Moreover `OnBuildBegin` is skipped if VisualStudio estimates it has nothing to build before debugging.

`OnBuildBegin` or (if skipped) `OnBuildDone` is always executed just after OnAfterExecute `Debug.Start` (tested on VS2010/2012/2013/2015).

Spying others command, I can see two commands `Build.SolutionConfigurations` (and  sometime also one or several `Debug.StartupProject`) are ran in between before/after execute `Debug.Start` (I observed this behavior only in in VS2013/2015).

1. OnBeforeExecute `Debug.Start`
2. OnBeforeExecute `Build.SolutionConfigurations`
3. OnAfterExecute `Build.SolutionConfigurations`
4. OnBeforeExecute `Build.SolutionConfigurations`
5. OnAfterExecute `Build.SolutionConfigurations`
6. OnBeforeExecute `Debug.StartupProjects`
7. OnAfterExecute `Debug.StartupProjects`
8. OnAfterExecute `Debug.Start`
9. OnBuildBegin
10. OnBuildDone

Hence we can infer that *a successful build will be followed by a Debug session* happens when one of these two events occurs:

- when a `Build.SolutionConfigurations` or a `Debug.StartupProjects` command is triggered in between before/after `Debug.Start` command.
- when there is less than a second between the last OnAfterExecute `Debug.Start` and the current `OnBuildBegin` or `OnBuildDone`.

As a side note the command `Debug.StartWithoutDebugging` plays the same role as `Debug.Start` when the user asks to start without debugging. Hence we can also infer *a successful build will be followed by a run (with no debug) session*

Comment: Nice one, except that I get the order    OnBeforeExecute Debug.Start   -> OnAfterExecute Debug.Start  ->   OnBuildBegin  ->  OnBuildDone    Anyway, this is enough to get the info "a successful build will be followed by a Debug session" thanks very much Serge

Comment: One question,  why do you have     if (commands != null)    ? In which case it is expected to be null? (I know how random behavior the VS API can have, yet still asking :)

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam I don't know a scenario when commands == null. Just over defensive coding :)

Comment: Thanks Sergey :) I understand