# What underlying VS command is fired?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I right-click on a selected project in the Solution explorer, and choose "Build" on the pop-up, I want to intercept that build command.

I have tried with "Build.BuildOnlyProject" and "Build.BuildSelection", but it doesn't seem that these are the correct ones.

How can I figure out which command is actually being called?

I can intercept the "Build.BuildSolution" command (since I have a VS Extension) when I right-click on the solution, but I want to do the same thing when I right-click on the project.

Comment: How exactly do you want to intercept and what are you trying to achieve. Understanding your scenario might help others to come up with solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to EnvDTE80.Commands2.BeforeExecute event and check the command name executing (see [How do I know from my VSIX that a build will be followed by a Debug session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865333/how-do-i-know-from-my-vsix-that-a-build-will-be-followed-by-a-debug-session)). This way you can find what command is fired and intercept it.

Comment: Thanks, this was awesome. Just what I was looking for. It turns out the command was "ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Build". I wouldn't have been able to guess it haha.