# Visual Studio Build Events - Determine if built from debugger

Tags: visual-studio, build

I make extensive use of the pre and post build events in visual studio, and I want to distinguish between doing a regular build (ctrl-shift B) and when the build was initiated by pressing the **start debugging** button (F5)

Anyone know of a way to do this?  I know you can distinguish between release and debug configurations using $(ConfigurationName), but this is not what I am looking for. For both of the above scenarios, the configuration is Debug.

Comment: It uses an extension, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865333/how-do-i-know-from-my-vsix-that-a-build-will-be-followed-by-a-debug-session