# Can I get my code to run directly after the Visual Studio "Clean Solution" command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

I'm creating my first Visual Studio extension and everything would just be perfect if I can get my code to run immediately after the Visual Studio "Clean Solution" command finishes execution.

I found `EnvDTE._dispBuildEvents_Event.OnBuildDone`, but can't seem to find it's cousin `OnCleanDone`.

Does an event like this exist at all? Or, is there a different approach I could take?

Thanks, giants!

Comment: You can monitor "Clean Solution" command execution using EnvDTE.CommandEvents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939128/84507

Comment: Thanks for your idea! However, I didn't get it to work, which is totally my bad, but in the process, I found out that `OnBuildDone` actually fires on the Clean Solution command, and the parameter `enum vsBuildAction` contains the value `vsBuildActionClean` which is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @JoepGeevers, since you have a workaround, I suggest you could add an answer here rather than a comment.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT thanks for reminding me, I just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `Clean Solution` is considered a `BuildEvent` and therefore fires `EnvDTE._dispBuildEvents_Event.OnBuildDone`.

All you need to do, is to check if parameter `Action == vsBuildAction.vsBuildActionClean`.

My full solution below (with two remarks):

- I get the warning that "One or more extensions were loaded using deprecated APIs", so I have some work to do, and will update this code snippet once I have it fixed. Maybe the naming conventions and lack of Generics should have been an indication that I'm doing this in an out-of-fashion manner
- If I don't keep an active reference to `DTE.Events.BuildEvents`, `OnBuildDone` won't fire. I don't know why yet.

  ```
  public sealed class OnCleanSolutionDoneExtension : Package
  {
      protected override void Initialize()
      {
          base.Initialize();

          this.BuildEvents.OnBuildDone += OnBuildDone;
      }

      void OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope scope, vsBuildAction action)
      {
          if (action == vsBuildAction.vsBuildActionClean)
          {
              // 
          }
      }

      private BuildEvents BuildEvents
      {
          get
          {
              if (this.buildEvents == null)
              {
                  this.buildEvents = this.DevelopmentToolsEnvironment.Events.BuildEvents;
              }

              return this.buildEvents;
          }
      }

      private BuildEvents buildEvents;

      private DTE DevelopmentToolsEnvironment
      {
          get
          {
              return this.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
          }
      }

      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
      {
          try
          {
              if (disposing)
              {
                  this.buildEvents.OnBuildDone -= OnBuildDone;

                  GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
              }
          }
          finally
          {
              base.Dispose(disposing);
          }
      }
  }
  ```